# Key pressing definition in map or menu - not working when sourcing a .vim file

Tags: vim

I implemented a function in /home/ioana/myfunction.vim, and, at the beginning of this file, I also added:

```
map <c-a><c-h> :Afunction

menu &Edit.Add\ function :Afunction<cr>
```

Both definitions are working fine when executing with my user (solaris and linux, vim 7.2). The problem appears when a colleague is opening gvim from his console, does :so /home/ioana/myfunction.vim and then tries to execute any map or menu which contains key pressing definitions - none of them is recognized as keys. The problem appears both in linux or solaris. Any other menu which does not contain keys are working fine.

Please help to identify the cause of key pressing recognition, as I need the file to be used by several colleagues. Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps he has `:` remapped? Have you tried a non-recursive mapping?

```
noremap <c-a><c-h> :Afunction
```

Comment: I found a method to make it work: add runtime! myfunction.vim in the .vimrc file